# nservicebus persistance data - what is it?

Tags: nservicebus

as I was reading thru documentation on nservicebus, I wasnt able to find what is persisted under Persistence section.

If nservicebus is a loosely coupled distributed library sending self-contained messages, what is there to persist? I dont understand.

With web app, when a user has a Session, we may choose to persist the Session in SQL Server, in Memory or somehow else, but with nservicebus there is no session to persist.

So, what is actually the Persistence in nservicebus? 
What sort of data that could be persisted and for what reason?

Answer (score 0):

Transports like RabbitMQ and Azure Service Bus natively support publish/subscribe. If an endpoint wants to receive published events, a 'subscription' to those events is stored inside those queuing technologies. Other queuing technologies don't support publish/subscribe natively, like MSMQ and Azure Storage Queues. NServiceBus mimics the behavior, but needs to store those subscriptions somewhere else.

Other things we can store are timeout and deferred messages and saga state. A saga is kind of a state machine (a workflow) and this state needs to be stored somewhere. Another feature [NServiceBus supports is the outbox](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/outbox/), which removes the need for distributed transactions by putting the message transaction and business transaction in the same database.

If you only use certain features, some transports allow you to do that natively. This removes the need for a persister. Sagas and Outbox always need persistence.